# Dynamically Updating Getter function in object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, redux, getter

In my constructor, I have state set as

```
this.state = {
  selectedProvider: '',
  selectedPort: '',
  selectedNetwork: '',
  networks: {
    MainNet: {
      disabled: false,
    },
    aTestNetwork: {
      get disabled() {
        return this.selectedProvider === 'aProvider';
      },
    },
}
```

I am using `this.setState()` to update the selectedProvider using an onClick function. However, the value of this.state.selectedProvider doesn't appear to be updating the value to be returned by the getter function named `disabled`.

I am using `this.state.networks` to list the networks in a dropdown menu and my intention is to have them listed as disabled or enabled dynamically based on the value of this.state.selectedProvider, and as stated, it looks like the getters value is only being generated once.

How can I get the return value of the getter to be updated dynamically?

Edit: Was able to assign this.selectedProvider a value properly using a setter and invoking it before calling the getter.

```
set provider(prov) {
  this.selectedProvider = prov;
},
get disabled() {
  return this.selectedProvider === 'aProvider';
},
```

Comment: In your `getter` function `this.selectedProvider` is undefined. I don't know what you assumed, but this way you won't be able to get the value of `selectedProvider`. I would suggest to make a utility function which checks `this.state.selectedProvider` and returns a boolean.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'm actually trying to avoid adding yet another function that checks for various conditions, so I thought I'd put it into the object. The above code *works correctly the first time*. The values returned by the getters do not update the second time `this. selectedProvider` is updated.

Comment: that's fine, but you can't use it this way.

Answer (score 1):

Since the `this` inside the getter refers to it's immediate host object, your best bet would be to bind the context:

```js
const self = this;
this.state = {
  selectedProvider: '',
  selectedPort: '',
  selectedNetwork: '',
  networks: {
    MainNet: {
      disabled: false
    },
    aTestNetwork: {
      get disabled () {
        return self.state.selectedProvider === 'aProvider';
      }
    }
  }
};
// test:
console.log(this.state.networks.aTestNetwork.disabled);
this.state.selectedProvider = 'aProvider';
console.log(this.state.networks.aTestNetwork.disabled);
```

Comment: Thanks. I already have my solution, but this looks like a good one as well.